# about MPxThreadedDeviceNode

Tags: maya

```
void somefuncname::threadHandler：
{
    ......

    enter code herestenter code hered::string tmp = std::string(buf);
    beginThreadLoop();
    {
        std::string * data= reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(buffer.ptr());
        data[0] = tmp;data[1]="";data[2]="";
        pushThreadData( buffer );
    }
    endThreadLoop();
    ......
}

void somefuncname::compute
{
    ......
    std::string* data= reinterpret_cast<std::string*>(buffer.ptr());
    MGlobal::displayInfo(data[0].c_str());
    ......enter code here
}
```

a problem： compile successfully create new nodes in the Maya. When live=1, an exception is thrown, Maya died, if I replace the std::string double does not have this problem.

Comment: It looks like your example code includes 'enter code here' twice. It would also help to know what the exception is.